# How to search irespective of Case sentive

Tags: jquery

On key press i am searching through a table to display values , but how to make this work irrespective of case insensitive

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#filter').on('input', function()
        {
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label:contains(' + val+ ')').closest('td')
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
        })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/216/

Comment: Use a `filter` to return elements that match your criteria E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/217/

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this. The closest to what you already have is probably to use a `filter()` callback, harmonising both needle and haystack to lowercase for the search:

```
var el = tr.find('label').filter(function(label) {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}).closest('td');
```

Also beware global vars - you were missing `var` before your `el` definition.